# IndexedDb. Insert items on empty (previously deleted)

Tags: indexeddb

I have a store with keyPath and autoincrement=true.
I have 100 items, I delete the 50'th. 
I cannot get to insert a new 50's....
The result is always the same: 100 items with the 50's occuping the keypath 101....
Is there any way to insert that '50' item ?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Not automatically. The key for a new record always increases. You'd have to manually keep track of which keys are deleted and manually set that key for a new record. See [the spec](https://w3c.github.io/IndexedDB/#key-generator-construct) for excruciating details, but this bit is relevant:

> A practical result of this is that the first key generated for an object store is always 1 (unless a higher numeric key is inserted first) and the key generated for an object store is always a positive integer higher than the highest numeric key in the store. The same key is never generated twice for the same object store unless a transaction is rolled back.